# Calculating Differential of multivariable functions the other way.

Tags: real-analysis

I never saw this approach before so I beg you to verify:

Is it possible to calculate the differential of, let's say $\partial_xf(x,y)$ at $(1,1)$ by:

\begin{equation} \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x}\,?\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as that limit is of the form $\frac 01$ and always evaluates to $0$ for continuous $f$. Instead, this would work: $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, then $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x,1)-f(1,1)}{x} = f(1,1)-f(1,1) = 0$$

which is clearly not what we're looking for since you can come up with a continuous function $f$ whose partial derivative at $(1,1)$ is not $0$